# Unnamed Apex:Param tag causes generated javascript function to have a syntax error

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I'm writing a page to get the value an `apex:selectList` is changed too, using the `onchange` attribute, and an `actionFunction`. Everything looks right, and compiles, but when I load the the page, the generated javascript for the function is missing quotes around (what looks like) a html input Id, and fails to create the `actionFunction`.

Specifically, this is the generated javascript function:

```
<script id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2" type="text/javascript">
    RerenderOutputPanel=function(j_id0:j_id1:j_id3){A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id1',null,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2','parameters':{'j_id0:j_id1:j_id3':(typeof j_id0:j_id1:j_id3!='undefined'&&j_id0:j_id1:j_id3!=null)?j_id0:j_id1:j_id3:'','j_id0:j_id1:j_id2':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2'} } )};
</script>
```

This causes the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `:`

When I remove my `apex:param` tag under my `apex:actionFunction`, the error goes away, and the generated code looks like this:

```
<script id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2" type="text/javascript">
    RerenderOutputPanel=function(){A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id1',null,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2','parameters':{'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2'} } )};
 </script>
```

I'm unsure where the value `j_id0:j_id1:j_id3` is coming from- I can't find it anywhere else in the generated html, except for this function definition.

What could I change about my markup to prevent this error from occurring?

Ideally I'm looking to not have to go to Salesforce support, as I do not have access to developer/premium support, but if this is a Salesforce issue, I have very few other options.

---

This is the code I've been using as a test case:

## Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="TestClass">

    <apex:form>

        <apex:actionFunction reRender="OutputPanel" name="RerenderOutputPanel" action="{!Rerender}">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedValue}" value="" /> <!-- removing this value removes the syntax error -->
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:selectList size="1" onchange="RerenderOutputPanel(this.value)" value="{!SelectedValue}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"></apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectList>

        <apex:outputPanel id="OutputPanel">
            Value: <apex:outputLabel>{!SelectedValue}</apex:outputLabel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

## Apex

```
public class TestClass {

    public TestClass() {}

    public List<SelectOption> Options {
        get {
            return new List<SelectOption>{
                new SelectOption('FirstId', 'FirstValue'),
                new SelectOption('SecondId', 'SecondValue'),
                new SelectOption('ThirdId', 'ThirdValue')
            };
        }
        set;
    }

    public String SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public PageReference Rerender() {
        return null; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stand down! I've figure this one out. It looks like the `j_id0:j_id1:j_id3` text is referencing the variable name, and when a name is not provided to the `apex:param` tag, the value passed to the javascript function is some auto-generated text, in this case, `j_id0:j_id1:j_id3`.

By adding a name to the `apex:param` tag, the parser uses that value instead of the automatic one, preventing the syntax error.

---

Interesting that this error isn't reported in a more understandable method (which is why I'm leaving this question open instead of deleting it in shame). Seems like an easy way to rectify this would be to require the name, or at least report an error if the `apex:param` tag is used without a `name`, as the child of an `apex:actionFunction` tag. What also strikes me as odd is how this generates a syntax error as a name, instead of a name which is valid in javascript.

---

Below is the updated, working test class & page.

## Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="TestClass">

    <apex:form>

        <apex:actionFunction reRender="OutputPanel" name="RerenderOutputPanel" action="{!Rerender}">
            <apex:param name="TestParam" assignTo="{!SelectedValue}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:selectList size="1" onchange="RerenderOutputPanel(this.value)" value="{!SelectedValue}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"></apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectList>

        <apex:outputPanel id="OutputPanel">
            Value: <apex:outputLabel>{!SelectedValue}</apex:outputLabel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

## Apex

```
public class TestClass {

    public TestClass() {}

    public List<SelectOption> Options {
        get {
            return new List<SelectOption>{
                new SelectOption('FirstId', 'FirstValue'),
                new SelectOption('SecondId', 'SecondValue'),
                new SelectOption('ThirdId', 'ThirdValue')
            };
        }
        set;
    }

    public String SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public PageReference Rerender() {
        return null; 
    }

}
```

Naming the `param` causes this javascript to render:

```
<script id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2" type="text/javascript">
    RerenderOutputPanel=function(TestParam){A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id1',null,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2','parameters':{'TestParam':(typeof TestParam!='undefined'&&TestParam!=null)?TestParam:'','j_id0:j_id1:j_id2':'j_id0:j_id1:j_id2'} } )};
</script>
```

Comment: I was just about to mention that. Name is realistically a required value. Also, I strongly recommend using a reRender attribute.